# Latency in sending HTTP Web Service Request from C#.NET to Wireshark on same VM

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, network-programming, tcp

We have a C# coded Windows Service that processes transactions by sending HTTP messages to a Web Services endpoint. The system, when under load, shows a latency of 1 to 32+ seconds between the time the C# code sends the request and Wireshark receives it, both on the same Virtual Machine (VM). As the C# Windows Service and Wireshark are on the same VM, there is no network involved. When we abort the connection in C# code, after a timeout period has elapsed (32 seconds), the request is eventually and strangely sent to and received by the Web Service endpoint. We do not believe the issue is due to hardware resources as this occurs on multiple environments including beefy production systems where the latency kicks-in at relatively low volumes.

We are using .NET Framework v4.6.1. The VM is Windows 2008 R2, SP1.

Questions: 
What is causing the latency? And how can we remove the latency?

Technical details:
This is the ServiceModel original configuration for the communication in app.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransaction">
      <security mode="Transport"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransaction1"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://.../" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransaction" contract="PaymentSwitchReference.ITransaction" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransaction"/>    
</client>
```

In the c# code, we create the object:

```
_client = new TransactionClient();       //TransactionClient class, proxy which contents the delegates and asynchronous calls to server
_client.ChargeAsync(req);                //Call to begin request sending

//In TransactionClient class:

public Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.ResponseCharge Charge(Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.Charge req) {
            return base.Channel.Charge(req);
}

 [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public System.IAsyncResult BeginCharge(Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.Charge req, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState) {             //Here is calling the service 
            return base.Channel.BeginCharge(req, callback, asyncState);
}

[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.ResponseCharge EndCharge(System.IAsyncResult result) {
            return base.Channel.EndCharge(result);
        }

private System.IAsyncResult OnBeginCharge(object[] inValues, System.AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState) {
            Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.Charge req = ((Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.Charge)(inValues[0]));
            return this.BeginCharge(req, callback, asyncState);
}

private object[] OnEndCharge(System.IAsyncResult result) {
            Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.ResponseCharge retVal = this.EndCharge(result);
            return new object[] {
                    retVal};
}

private void OnChargeCompleted(object state) {
      if ((this.ChargeCompleted != null)) {
                InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs e = ((InvokeAsyncCompletedEventArgs)(state));
                this.ChargeCompleted(this, new ChargeCompletedEventArgs(e.Results, e.Error, e.Cancelled, e.UserState));
      }
}

public void ChargeAsync(Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.Charge req) {
            this.ChargeAsync(req, null);
}

public void ChargeAsync(Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.Charge req, object userState) { //Creates the delegates and invoke asynchronous communication.
      if ((this.onBeginChargeDelegate == null)) {
          this.onBeginChargeDelegate = new BeginOperationDelegate(this.OnBeginCharge);
      }
      if ((this.onEndChargeDelegate == null)) {
          this.onEndChargeDelegate = new EndOperationDelegate(this.OnEndCharge);
      }
      if ((this.onChargeCompletedDelegate == null)) {
          this.onChargeCompletedDelegate = new System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback(this.OnChargeCompleted);
      }
      base.InvokeAsync(this.onBeginChargeDelegate, new object[] {
                 req}, this.onEndChargeDelegate, this.onChargeCompletedDelegate, userState);
}
```

When the test is running and the number of requests starts growing we can see an ever increasing time delay between BeginCharge and the transaction being sent through Wireshark on the same VM. We eventually abort the connection (after 32 seconds) and we receive the following expected Exception from OnChargeCompleted delegate:

```
> e
> {Plpm.Csp.PaymentService.PaymentSwitchReference.ChargeCompletedEventArgs}
>     Cancelled: false
>     Error: {"An error (The request was aborted: The request was canceled.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel."}
>     Result: 'e.Result' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException'
>     UserState: null
>     cancelled: false
>     error: {"An error (The request was aborted: The request was canceled.) occurred while transmitting data over the HTTP channel."}
>     results: null
>     userState: null
```

This timeout abort causes our service to complete with this exception message. However, at the same time that our service aborts the connection, the request is strangely being sent successfully to the Web Service endpoint on another VM. We can see in Wireshark how it is sent and arrives after the abort.

We have tried changing the config file as follows by adding the system.web configuration, as well as transferMode and Timeouts parameters:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransaction" transferMode="StreamedRequest" closeTimeout="00:10:00" openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransaction1"/>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://.../" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITransaction" contract="PaymentSwitchReference.ITransaction" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITransaction"/>    
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

And in C# code, we tried adding the following KeepAlive parameter:

```
var customBinding = new CustomBinding(_client.Endpoint.Binding);
var transportElement = customBinding.Elements.Find<HttpTransportBindingElement>();
transportElement.KeepAliveEnabled = false;
_client.Endpoint.Binding = customBinding;
_client.ChargeAsync(req);
```

However, the outcome is the same in that we continue to see latency.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this is due to a WCF setting called “**maxconnection**”.

This is the maximum number of concurrent outgoing HTTP connections allowed to a server. In our app, we were not explicitly setting this, and so, the default value of ‘2’ is being used. The limitation of this default value causes traffic to be queued during times of heavy load. This manifests itself in the latency problem described in this question.
The solution, and Microsoft’s recommendation, is to increase the number to 12 * number of processors. If changing this setting, Microsoft also recommend changing other related settings. You can read more about this at this link (search for “maxconnection”): [Tuning .NET Application Performance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647813.aspx)

According to Microsoft, the reason the default value of ‘2’ concurrent requests is so low is because this is what the official HTTP specification recommends. This makes sense if the client connecting is a user-facing app like a web browser but not for a server-side app that acts like a proxy (as in our case).  More information about why ‘2’ is the default setting can be found at this link: 
[Why Only Two Concurrent Requests for WCF Load Testing](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wenlong/2009/02/08/why-only-two-concurrent-requests-for-wcf-load-testing/)